# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app.area_id

Tags: python, django

When I run `./manage.py migrate`,error happens `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app.area_id` .
`models.py` is

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='area', null=True)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area', default="")

class Prefecture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='city')
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area')

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='region')
            prefecture = models.ForeignKey('Prefecture')

class Price(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='price')
            PRICE_RANGE = (
                ('a', 'under500'),
                ('b', '500-1000'),
                ('c', 'upper1000'),
            )
    price_range = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PRICE_RANGE)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City')
```

When I wrote `area = models.ForeignKey('Area')`,I got an error 
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'area' to transaction without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows). Please select a fix: 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column) 2) Quit, and let me add a default in `models.py`.
What is wrong? How can I fix this?

Now models.py is

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='area', null=True)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area', default="")

class Prefecture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='city')
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area', null=True, blank=True)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='region')
            prefecture = models.ForeignKey('Prefecture', null=True, blank=True)

class Price(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='price')
            PRICE_RANGE = (
                ('a', 'under500'),
                ('b', '500-1000'),
                ('c', 'upper1000'),
            )
    price_range = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PRICE_RANGE)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', null=True, blank=True)
```

I also got same error.I already tried cache.clear() .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the model below you are trying to add area as a ForeignKey. Since this `Prefecture` table has some data already Django does not know what to add in area field for existing rows.

```
class Prefecture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='city')
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area') # non null-able field Django does
                                     # not know what to add
```

Simple solution. Provide a default or add null

```
class Prefecture(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='city')
        area = models.ForeignKey('Area', null=True)
```

Note: for all existing rows in `Prefecture` now `area` field will be null. You can add this field now for new rows.

Comment: thx,ur comments.I tried ur codes,but I got same error.I updated my question,if u know something please help me.

Comment: in Prefecture model you still have `area = models.ForeignKey('Area')` you have to change it to this `area = models.ForeignKey('Area', null=True, blank=True)` @user8504021

Comment: I tried ur codes,but i got same error.I updated myquestion code,if u find still some error ,please tell me.

Comment: I can think of only one error now In `User` model change this `area = models.ForeignKey('Area', default="")` to `area = models.ForeignKey('Area', null=True, blank=True)` If it still does not work try a fresh migrate by deleting the db

Answer (score 2):

You'll first need to **delete** the previously generated migration file.

Otherwise, even if you fix your `models.py`, you will keep getting the same error because `./manage.py migrate` will keep trying to apply the previous migration.

After you delete the previously generated migration file, use the following:

```
area = models.ForeignKey('Area', blank=True, null=True)
```

This will make the `area` attribute optional, and you will be able to generate a new migration file and proceed with `./manage.py migrate`.

After you've done that, you can optionally write a *data migration* script to fill in the missing `area` attributes. You can read more about in in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/writing-migrations/).

You can also fill-in this attribute manually for your existing data, instead of writing a migration script (for instance, buy directly updating your database or by using django-admin).

Once you make sure that all your data has the `area` attribute filled-in, you can make your final change:

```
area = models.ForeignKey('Area')
```

When you apply this migration, you will simply add a NOT NULL constraint to this field in your database, and it should be OK if you filled-in the data in the previous step.

Comment: Deleting the previous ("un-commited") migration files was the key!

Comment: You can specify `default=someUserId` instead of `null=True` if you want to assign a default value to items already in the database that were created before this field was added to the model.

Answer (score 0):

as the above answer, [null = True] is available,
i recommend another [default = None] is also available

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible you have not executed `makemigration` and `migrate`.

I faced below error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   adminapp_responses.created_by_id

But after `makemigration` and `migrate`, it is gone.