# How to use add(), set() and clear() methods of ManyRelatedManager in Django ManyToManyField with a through class?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, manytomanyfield, manyrelatedmanager

I have models as follows,

```
Class Bank(models.Model):
    customers = models.ManyToManyField(Customer,'banks', through='bank_customer')

Class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

Class Bank_customer(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
Class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

How do I add `Customer` objects to `Bank`? The following does not work

```
bank.customers.add(customer)
```

Here `bank` and `customer` are saved instances of their classes. Doing this violates `not_null` constraint for `city` ForeignKey in `Bank_customer` table.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: @iklinac This link does not explain how many_to_many works with the through model. It only explains the simple manytomany relationship.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: @iklinac Thanks, this does explain, the add() and clear() methods. But, in the set() method, it only allows for same ```through_fields``` for the set of through classes. How do I use set() with unique through_fields for each of the related objects in the list?

Answer (score 2):

First, some general comments. I'm no expert, but I would make this changes to the models to start.

- Be carefull with the reserved word `class`, it must be all lowercase.
- When you define the classes, the order is important. The classes that inherit or are backward-related must be [defined last](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2009-August/071271.html). (eg: `Bank` must be defined after `Customer`, if not you'll have an error like *"Customer is not defined"* or something like that).
- I think that you may need a `name` attribute/field in the `Bank` model. I mean, banks have a name.
- In the `Bank` class I think it's better to explicitly use the related name keyword: `related_name='banks'`. It makes readability better.
- It's more Pythonic to name classes using the CapWords convention ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)).
  Use `BankCustomer` instead of `Bank_customer` model.

---

**About your specific question.**

I did this:

```
c1 = Customer(name="Guido van Rossum")
c1.save()
b1 = Bank(name="Bank of America")
b1.save()
```

Then I did `b1.customers.add(c1)` and this error was raised: `IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app2_bankcustomer.city_id`.
It seems that it was expecting `city_id` to have `null=True` in the `BankCustomer`.

I continued with:

```
ct1 = City('New York')
ct1.save()
bc1 = BankCustomer(customer=c1, bank=b1, city=ct1)
bc1.save()
```

And then when I did `b1.customers.add(c1)` no errors were raised.

The problem is the `IntegrityError` error, apparently:

> `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL` --> this is a very common
> error for beginners. It means that you have a field that is
> `null=False` (aka the `default`) and you're trying to create that
> model WITHOUT that field having any data.
> ([source](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/comments/13752))

So you can make a little change to the `BankCustomer`. You add `null=True` in the `city` field.

```
class BankCustomer(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.customer} - {self.bank} - {self.city}'
```

(*Don't forget to run makemigrations and migrate*)

After this, no errors are raised.

Some other sources that discuss the issue:

[django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app.area_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088488/django-db-utils-integrityerror-not-null-constraint-failed-app-area-id)

[django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: products_product.image ERROR WITH IMAGE FIELD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733221/django-db-utils-integrityerror-not-null-constraint-failed-products-product-ima/46497052)

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21783

https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/polls-not-null-constraint-failed/4396/2

https://github.com/sibtc/django-beginners-guide/issues/20

---

If you check the admin you'll see that the `Bank` model only accepts `name` and no `customers`.

[image]

Which I think is logical because you want to use the `BankCustomer` (in your code: `Bank_customer`).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find the django doc for it. however looking at the Django3.1's source code of `ManyRelatedManager__add`, it accepts `through_defaults` parameter

```
def add(self, *objs, through_defaults=None):
...
                self._add_items(
                    self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs,
                    through_defaults=through_defaults,
                )
...
```

so, instead of

```
bank.customers.add(customer)
```

try

```
bank.customers.add(customer, through_defaults={'city_id':SOME_CITY_OBJ_ID_YOU_WANT})
```

this works on `.set()` function as well